# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying store & get data in `NSUserDefaults`, when application launch at first time value for "token" in `NSUserDefaults` is nil. On application launch I am trying to get it from `standardUserDefaults()`, but it fails & give an error as:

`EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`.

Follow is the code:

```
var prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let value : AnyObject! = prefs.objectForKey("token") as AnyObject!
```

Comment: Which line is generating the error?

Comment: I am able to run your code without any problems in Xcode 6 Beta 2. Which Xcode r u using? Try cleaning the project, resetting the simulator and running it again.

Comment: On: let value : AnyObject! = prefs.objectForKey("token") as AnyObject!

Comment: can you also share the code storing data?

Comment: I am using Xcode 6 Beta 1

Comment: Which beta? It might be Xcode, try updating to latest beta.

Comment: Thanks @reecon. I will try with latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to run your code **without any problems** in Xcode 6 Beta 2.
**Try updating** to the latest Xcode 6 beta from [developer center](https://developer.apple.com/).

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what I would expect if there is no object for the key "token".

AnyObject! means "you are allowed to assign values that *might* be nil, but I guarantee it won't happen, so please crash when it happens".

Comment: You are wrong. The value of `value` can be nil. This is all what `AnyObject!` means. This is not an assert statement.

Comment: @reecon That is not the use case of AnyObject!, it means: Once set to a value it may not be nil anymore. Technically it could, but you should not test AnyObject! for nil. gnasher729 is absolutely correct. By convention from Apple AnyObject! should not be nil after first set.

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem with your code. I'm able to run it.

```
pref: AnyObject! = {
    value = None
}
```

What's the version of your Xcode?